# Elasticsearch combining queries with Boolean query

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I'm trying to combine mutiple queries in elasticsearch using a boolean query but the result is not what I'm expecting. For example:

If I have the following documents (among others):

```
DOC 1:
{
   "name":"Iphone 5",
   "product_suggestions":{
      "input":[
         "iphone 5",
         "apple"
      ]
   },
   "description":"Iphone 5 - The almost last version",
   "brand":"Apple",
   "brand_facet":"Apple",
   "state_id":"2",
   "user_state_description":"Almost New",
   "product_type_id":"1",
   "current_price":350,
   "finish_date":"2014/06/20 14:12",
   "finish_date_ms":1403273520
}

DOC 2:
{
   "name":"Apple II Lisa",
   "product_suggestions":{
      "input":[
         "apple ii lisa",
         "apple"
      ]
   },
   "description":"Make a offer and I Apple II Lisa!!",
   "brand":"Apple",
   "brand_facet":"Apple",
   "state_id":"2",
   "user_state_description":"Used",
   "product_type_id":"1",
   "current_price":150,
   "finish_date":"2014/06/15 16:12",
   "finish_date_ms":1402848720
}

DOC 3:
{
   "name":"Iphone 5s",
   "product_suggestions":{
      "input":[
         "iphone 5s",
         "apple"
      ]
   },
   "description":"Iphone 5s 32Gb like new with a few scratches bla bla bla",
   "brand":"Apple",
   "brand_facet":"Apple",
   "state_id":"1",
   "user_state_description":"New",
   "product_type_id":"2",
   "current_price":510.1,
   "finish_date":"2014/06/10 14:12",
   "finish_date_ms":1402409520
}

DOC 4:
{
   "name":"Iphone 4s",
   "product_suggestions":{
      "input":[
         "iphone 4s",
         "apple"
      ]
   },
   "description":"Iphone 4s 16Gb Mint conditions and unlocked to all network",
   "brand":"Apple",
   "brand_facet":"Apple",
   "state_id":"1",
   "user_state_description":"Almost New",
   "product_type_id":"2",
   "current_price":385,
   "finish_date":"2014/06/12 16:12",
   "finish_date_ms":1402589520
}
```

And if I run the following query (Get all documents and facets with the keyword "Apple" that the finish_date_ms is bigger than 1402869581)

```
{
  "from" : 1,
  "size" : 20,
  "query" : {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : {
        "query_string" : {
          "query" : "apple",
          "default_operator" : "and",
          "analyze_wildcard" : true
        }
      },
      "must_not" : {
        "range" : {
          "finish_date_ms" : {
            "from" : null,
            "to" : 1402869581,
            "include_lower" : true,
            "include_upper" : false
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "facets" : {
    "brand" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "brand_facet",
        "size" : 10
      }
    },
    "product_type_id" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "product_type_id",
        "size" : 10
      }
    },
    "state_id" : {
      "terms" : {
        "field" : "state_id",
        "size" : 10
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns:

```
{
   "took":5,
   "timed_out":false,
   "_shards":{
      "total":5,
      "successful":5,
      "failed":0
   },
   "hits":{
      "total":1,
      "max_score":0.18392482,
      "hits":[

      ]
   },
   "facets":{
      "brand":{
         "_type":"terms",
         "missing":0,
         "total":1,
         "other":0,
         "terms":[
            {
               "term":"Apple",
               "count":1
            }
         ]
      },
      "product_type_id":{
         "_type":"terms",
         "missing":0,
         "total":1,
         "other":0,
         "terms":[
            {
               "term":1,
               "count":1
            }
         ]
      },
      "state_id":{
         "_type":"terms",
         "missing":0,
         "total":1,
         "other":0,
         "terms":[
            {
               "term":2,
               "count":1
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

And should return only the document DOC1. If I remove the range query, returns all the documents that has Apple word. If I remve the "term" query then n document is returns, so I presume the problem is in the range query.

Can anyone point me in the right direction with this?

One other important thing, all this query is to be implemented in java (if this help).
Thanks!
(sory for this huge post)

Comment: In the MUST clause on which field you want to query on ... I can not see that

Comment: I want to query in all fields, so that's why I did not put the field name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake. (newbie mistake to be honest)

The problem was not in the range query but in the begging of the Json: The from field is set to 1 but the result is only one record so this should be 0!!

Thanks for everything!!